# Long click for child item in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, drag, onlongclicklistener

I implement ExpandableListView DragNDrop for child item using this source https://github.com/sreekumarsh/android/tree/master/Drag%20N%20Drop. All main functional are in class, which extends ExpandableListView. It override onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) method, and long click functionality I indicate like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return touchHandler(event);
}

public boolean touchHandler(final MotionEvent event) {
    final int action = event.getAction();
    final int x = (int) event.getX();
    final int y = (int) event.getY();
    if (prevY < 0) {
        prevY = y;
    }

    int flatPosition = pointToPosition(x, y);
    dragRatio = getHeight() / screenHeight;
    long packagedPosition = getExpandableListPosition(flatPosition);

    Log.i(TAG, "Motion event " + event.getAction());

    Runnable mLongPressed = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.i("in thread", "ok");
            event.setLocation(x, y);
            touchHandler(event);
            pressedItem = true;
            isLongPressed = false;
        }
    };

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && getPackedPositionType(packagedPosition) == 1) {
        if (dragOnLongPress) {
            Log.i("pressedItem", pressedItem + "");
            if (pressedItem) {
                mDragMode = true;
                pressedItem = false;
                Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vibrator.vibrate(50);
            } else {
                pressedItem = true;
                Log.i("thread: ", "starting");
                handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, 500);
                return true;
            }
        } else if (x < dragOffset) {
            mDragMode = true;
        }
    }

    if (!mDragMode) {
        /** when user action on other areas */
        if ((pressedItem && Math.abs(prevY - y) > 30)
                || event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            pressedItem = false;
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

 switch(action){
     case:MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: bla-bla
     case:MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: bla-bla
     case:MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: bla-bla

 }
```

And when it normal work it have Log like this:

```
 I/Motion event MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
 I/pressedItem: false
 I/thread: starting
 I/in thread: ok
 I/Motion event MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
 I/pressedItem: true
 I/Motion event MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
 I/Motion event MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
```

But when long click not detected:

```
I/Motion event MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
I/pressedItem: false
I/Motion event MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
I/Motion event MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
I/Motion event MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
I/Motion event MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
...
I/Motion event MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
I/Motion event MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
```

and my dragmod not turn.

In both cases child item press are identical, but it can work different. MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE show while is Presed. It can be on custom roms or on htc sense. In stock ROM it work almost always fine. How I can fix it? If you have additional questions, please tell me.

Comment: long click must necessarily be in the adapter?

Comment: it must nessessarily be in class with extends ExpandableListView. I can`t use some view in adapter and set OnLongClickListener for this view. It work in my expandableListView class.